Can I use the hypergeometric distribution to calculate draw odds for 2 variables from a single population?
I would like to program a card-drawing calculator the give the odds of there being at least x cards of set A and y cards of set B, where sets A and B are distinct populations in set C of a given number of cards, after drawing z cards randomly from the deck.
For example, if a deck has 4 spades and 4 hearts, the calculator could give the odds of, say, drawing at least 2 hearts and 1 spade after 15 draws.
My current algorithm sums iterations of a range of draw odds for drawing exactly a specified number of cards for each applicable amount of x (between the minimum number of x to be drawn and the amount of cards drawn minus however many are required to satisfy drawing at least y cards of set B) multiplied by draw odds for drawing y or more cards from set B where z and the deck size are reduced by i (in an attempt to account for knowing that i cards are from set A).
$\sum_{i=x}^{z-y}(odds)of(drawnA = i)where(deck = default size) * (odds)of(drawnB >= y)where(deck = default size - i )and(z = default size - i) $
The calculator is very close to the values it should return, but always falls short. I am wondering if this is because they hypergeometric distribution cannot be applied here, whereas some distribution that accounts for multiple variables would be applicable. I suspect that this algorithm may be flawed because subtracting i from both the deck size and z each iteration can technically result in an error when the number of cards drawn is so high that the population size of cards chosen from (deck size - some large i) is less than B

[1] I suppose you are using odds loosely, for probability [2] You can certainly use the  multivariate hypergeometric distribution, classifying the variables as x, y, and "others"

Are you referring to this distribution (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_hypergeom.html)? Based on the description, I am not sure this one can work and do not know where to find the correct distribution.

Presumably your mention of the hypergeometric distribution means this is drawing without replacement.
If the total number of starting cards is $n$, of which $n_A$ are type A (your $x$) and $n_B$ are type B (your $y$) and so $n-n_A-n_B$ are other types, and you draw $z$ cards and want to know the probability of exactly $a$ type A and $b$ type B cards being drawn, then this probability is
$$\frac{{n_A \choose a}{n_B \choose b}{n-n_A-n_B \choose z-a-b}}{{n \choose z}}$$
and you would then want to sum over all the cases you are interested in and which have positive probabilities.  It can be seen as the product of two hypergeometric probabilities: $\frac{{n_A \choose a}{n-n_A \choose z-a}}{{n \choose z}}$ and $\frac{{n_B \choose b}{n-n_A-n_B \choose n-a-b}}{{n-n_A \choose z-a}}$.
In your particular example, if $n$ is large then this sum may be unwieldy and you might prefer to use inclusion-exclusion for "at least $2$ hearts and $1$ spade", i.e. not $0$ spades and neither $0$ hearts nor $1$ heart.  So
$$1\!-\!\frac{{n_A \choose 0}{n-n_A \choose z-0}}{{n \choose z}} \!-\!\frac{{n_B \choose 0}{n-n_B \choose z-0}}{{n \choose z}} \!-\!\frac{{n_B \choose 1}{n-n_B \choose z-1}}{{n \choose z}} \!+\!\frac{{n_A \choose 0}{n_B \choose 0}{n-n_A-n_B \choose z-0-0}}{{n \choose z}} \!+\!\frac{{n_A \choose 0}{n_B \choose 1}{n-n_A-n_B \choose z-0-1}}{{n \choose z}}$$
which can clearly be simplified.

Thanks for the explanation. I can see this formula is correct and was able to code with it to get the correct answer. I was trying to use another distribution (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_hypergeom.html) but am not sure, given the description, that it can work.

@vochoa213 Your linked expression for the multivariate hypergeometric probability mass function is (when $k=3$) essentially the same as my first expression.
